# mysql syntax clarification ' ' = ' '

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I'm in the process of learning PHP and MySQL. I came across an example of a SQL injection from the PHP man page, where the final injected SQL query was:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='aidan' AND password='' OR ''=''
```

I'm confused about what the `OR ''=''` means in this context? I know what that statement does, but I'm just trying to understand how it can be used in another scenario, and what the `''=''` signifies.

Thanks!

Comment: `OR ''=''`is a condition that will always be true (an empty string will always match an empty string; and ORing that with the user/password check will always return as TRUE even if the user and password don't match

Comment: If the password or '' is equal to '' the result will be the user aidan, so this is always true

Comment: So you should hashing the password string before checking it using SQL query and of course, the password should be stored as hashed string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were accepting a query in the format of `SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='aidan' AND password='$password'` a user could fill in `' OR ''='` for the password which will close out the password field and then allow the SQL query to check if `''=''` which will return `true` and cause them to gain access without entering a valid password.

Answer (score 4):

1. `''=''` evaluates always to **true**.
2. The whole condition `password='' OR ''=''` evaluates therefore also to **true**.

→ The password will not be checked and you are able to gain user access without a correct password.

Answer (score 1):

It's just an expression that means true, it's not likely to be used on other scenarios